# VS Code Drive .C does not exist

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using this setup (via VS Code -> about)

```
Version: 1.82.2 (user setup)
Commit: abd2f3db4bdb28f9e95536dfa84d8479f1eb312d
Date: 2023-09-14T05:55:25.390Z
Electron: 25.8.1
ElectronBuildId: 23779380
Chromium: 114.0.5735.289
Node.js: 18.15.0
V8: 11.4.183.29-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19045
```

No idea why it says Windows NT, I'm using Win 10.

When ever I want to run something in the console I get this error

```
python : Das Laufwerk wurde nicht gefunden. Ein Laufwerk mit dem Namen ".C" ist nicht vorhanden.
In Zeile:1 Zeichen:1
n. Ein Laufwerk mit dem Namen ".C" ist nicht vorhanden.
In Zeile:1 Zeichen:1
+ python -u "c:\Users\felix\OneDrive\Dokumente\UZH\HS23\Datenanalysis I ...
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (.C:String) [], DriveNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveNotFound
```

Translated with DeepL:

```
python : The drive was not found. A drive with the name ".C" does not exist.
In line:1 character:1
n. A drive with the name ".C" does not exist.
In line:1 character:1
+ python -u "c:\Users\felix\OneDrive\Documents\UZH\HS23\DataAnalysis I ...
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo : ObjectNotFound: (.C:String) [], DriveNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveNotFound
```

I can still run stuff with the normal console (cmd), just not in VS Code. It was working yesterday and now it suddenly stopped working. My guess is that something PATH variable is wrong and VS Code suddenly lost the ability to locate the C drive. But I don't really now enough about this to fix it. Can someone help me out?

EDIT:
When I use Ctrl + Alt + N, it does not work. But When I use F5 or Ctrl + F5 I get the error message but it still executes the code.

Comment: Is it possible something in your PATH has an extra `.` at the start? https://superuser.com/questions/1021310/powershell-a-drive-c-does-not-exist (Also, you say that CMD works fine, but it would be good to check whether you can run from Powershell outside VSCode)

Comment: @slothrop I am not sure what you mean with the PowerShell, but I opened PowerShell (Win + R -> PowerShell) and run a python file. It worked.

Comment: Right, my point was that the error you show in the question comes from Powershell inside VSCode. So if you compare that to CMD outside VSCode: then you don't know which of the two factors (CMD vs PS, or inside vs outside VSCode) makes the difference. But now, you've narrowed the cause down to something in VSCode.

Comment: @slothrop Do you have any idea what the problem could be, or how to narrow it down any further? I'm still puzzelnd by the fact that it just stoppend working from one day to an other. Also I have no PATH starting with ```.```

Comment: I'm guessing, but this could be relevant: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/22073#issuecomment-1734290798 Suggested fix there is to install the pre-release version of the Python extension in VSCode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to all the comments I found a fix:

- Switching to the pre-release version of the Python extension
- reloading VS Code
- closing and reopening all terminal windows

fixed it.