# VS Code numpy array endlessly expanding in debugger variables section

Tags: python, numpy, visual-studio-code, debugpy

Given a simple python program like

```
import numpy as np
my_list = [1,2,3,4,5]
my_array = np.array(my_list)
```

I can now use break points and the debugger to watch the variables

[image]

I can also expand them

[image]

for a list it shows all the elements neatly listed. This is esspecially helpful if I want to look at nested lists. However for the array it does not expand like it does for the list. It used to do it in the past. I can expand for example the `T` variable but it just expands into itself. Like I get the same thing as when I expanded the array in the first place. Alos I can repeat that endlessly

[image]

This all started when [I had to switch to the pre-relases version of the Python extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77187399/vs-code-drive-c-does-not-exist). I've switched back now, but it didn't helped.

My VS Code is:

```
Version: 1.85.0 (user setup)
Commit: af28b32d7e553898b2a91af498b1fb666fdebe0c
Date: 2023-12-06T20:48:09.019Z
Electron: 25.9.7
ElectronBuildId: 25551756
Chromium: 114.0.5735.289
Node.js: 18.15.0
V8: 11.4.183.29-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19045
```

Also this wierd error messages started to show up at the same time, as the behavior of the debugger changed, aka when I had to switch to the pre-relases version of the Python extension. So maybe they are related to this problem.

```
2023-12-15 11:41:41.416 [info] [Error - 11:41:41 AM] Server initialization failed.
2023-12-15 11:41:41.417 [info]   Message: Pending response rejected since connection got disposed
  Code: -32097 
2023-12-15 11:41:41.417 [info] [Info  - 11:41:41 AM] Connection to server got closed. Server will restart.
2023-12-15 11:41:41.417 [info] true
2023-12-15 11:41:41.418 [info] [Error - 11:41:41 AM] Python Jedi client: couldn't create connection to server.
2023-12-15 11:41:41.418 [info]   Message: Pending response rejected since connection got disposed
  Code: -32097 
2023-12-15 11:41:41.419 [info] [Error - 11:41:41 AM] Restarting server failed
2023-12-15 11:41:41.419 [info]   Message: Pending response rejected since connection got disposed
  Code: -32097 
2023-12-15 11:41:41.419 [info] [Error - 11:41:41 AM] Server process exited with code 1.
2023-12-15 11:41:41.797 [info] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\felix\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.22.1\pythonFiles\run-jedi-language-server.py", line 9, in <module>
    from jedi_language_server.cli import cli
  File "c:\Users\felix\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.22.1\pythonFiles\lib\jedilsp\jedi_language_server\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from importlib_metadata import version
  File "c:\Users\felix\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.22.1\pythonFiles\lib\jedilsp\importlib_metadata\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    import zipp
  File "c:\Users\felix\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.22.1\pythonFiles\lib\jedilsp\zipp\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .py310compat import text_encoding
  File "c:\Users\felix\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.22.1\pythonFiles\lib\jedilsp\zipp\py310compat.py", line 5
    def _text_encoding(encoding, stacklevel=2, /):  # pragma: no cover
                                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

2023-12-15 11:41:41.817 [info] [Error - 11:41:41 AM] Server process exited with code 1.
2023-12-15 11:41:41.819 [info] [Error - 11:41:41 AM] Server initialization failed.
2023-12-15 11:41:41.819 [info]   Message: Pending response rejected since connection got disposed
  Code: -32097 
2023-12-15 11:41:41.819 [info] [Error - 11:41:41 AM] The Python Jedi server crashed 5 times in the last 3 minutes. The server will not be restarted. See the output for more information.
2023-12-15 11:41:41.819 [info] [Error - 11:41:41 AM] Python Jedi client: couldn't create connection to server.
2023-12-15 11:41:41.819 [info]   Message: Pending response rejected since connection got disposed
  Code: -32097 
2023-12-15 11:41:41.819 [info] [Error - 11:41:41 AM] Restarting server failed
2023-12-15 11:41:41.819 [info]   Message: Pending response rejected since connection got disposed
  Code: -32097
```

Comment: You are asking two completely different questions (one about expanding, and one about an error). Please focus your question to one question only, so either the one about expanding or the one about the error. But for the second issue you should provide the minimal code to reproduce that, as it doesn't reproduce with the three lines of code you have shared (which relate to your first question only).

Comment: @trincot I have included the error message because it showed up at the same time are my other problem. So maybe they are related. Also I get this error every time I start VSC, and sometimes while working in it. So the minimal code would be 0 lines.

Comment: I can confirm they are not related. Please focus on one problem only, otherwise it will be considered to be too broad and closed by the community.

Comment: Eh, with .T I would expect this to be the intended behavior. For 1D array .T (transpose) is just the same array. And the same for recursive .T, like my_array.T.T.T.T.T is still the same.

Comment: please add the version number of your Python extension to your question post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is/was a bug in debugpy: [Can no longer expand Numpy arrays to view elements
#1408](https://github.com/microsoft/debugpy/issues/1408) and [namedtuple are not rendered in the variable browser as expected #1477](https://github.com/microsoft/debugpy/issues/1477). The bug was due to breakage from PR [GH-1230 Use find_namespace_packages() #1374](https://github.com/microsoft/debugpy/pull/1374). It is fixed by PR [Fix #1408, #1477 #1484](https://github.com/microsoft/debugpy/pull/1484). Sit tight and wait for the fix to be released.

For your reference / learning purposes, that issue ticket was found by googling "`github vscode python issues debugger variables numpy array`".